# CSS Issue for a.selected

Tags: css

I have a question about how to modify the color of a link that has been selected.
http://www.northernvirginiapaintingcontractors.com  Click "Contact Us" then 1 of the Links.

I can't determine why this color changes to purple.  If anyone can see this I would appreciate it.

I think that this has something to do with either of these definitions:

```
.contactmenu li a:link {
/*float: left;*/
text-decoration: none;
color: #A6BDCB;    
} 

.contactmenu li a:hover, .contactmenu li a.selected {                 
/*color: #B6B6B6;*/
color: #A6BDCB;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Here is the complete related CSS:

```
.contactblocktheme {                    
/*border:5px solid #cd0000;*/
padding:0;                                 
}

.contactblocktheme p {
padding: 1px 1px 1px 2px;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 13px;
/*background-color: navy;*/
width: auto;
}

.contactblocktheme {                    
/*border:5px solid #cd0000;*/
padding:0;                                 
}

.contactblocktheme p {
padding: 1px 1px 1px 2px;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 13px;
/*background-color: orange;*/
width: auto;
}

.contactblocktheme .column {
padding: 6px 3px 0 0;
font-family: Arial Black;
font-size: 12px;
/*background-color: olive;*/
}

.contactmenu {
width:122px;       
/*padding:10px;*/
position:absolute;
visibility:hidden;
border:1px solid #D7D7D7;
border-top-width:1px;
/*background-color: yellow;*/
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #c8c8c8;    
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #c8c8c8;
/*box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #c8c8c8;*/
}

.contactmenu .column {       
float:left;
text-align:left;
/*background-color:#4F4D4D;*/
background-color: #D7D7D7;
}

.contactmenu .column ul {
margin: 0 0 0 4px;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
list-style:none;
}

.contactmenu .column ul li {
margin-bottom: 7px;
}


.contactmenu a{
}

.contactmenu li a:link {
/*float: left;*/
text-decoration: none;
color: #A6BDCB;    
} 

.contactmenu li a:hover, .contactmenu li a.selected {                 
/*color: #B6B6B6;*/
/*color: #A6BDCB;*/
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Your link does not appear to work. Try setting `a:visited`, as well.

Comment: @showdev   I changed from selected to-  .contactmenu li a.visited did not change anything

Comment: Possible to fix your link? Or post a jFiddle? Or post your HTML?

Comment: @showdev I put all of the relevent css in the question, and I can't really create a fiddle for this whole menu

Comment: Why would somebody down-vote my question? because it is easy for you and not for me?

Comment: What I meant was, change `.contactmenu li a:link` to `.contactmenu li a:link,.contactmenu li a:visited`. That doesn't help?

Comment: @showdev unfortunately I can't post code on a comment, the solution was very easy because there was a conflict in the css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a `:visited` style on `.contactmenu li a`. This style could match the style you used for `:link`.

```
.contactmenu li a:visited {
  /* styles here */  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a conflict in the CSS with this definition:

```
.contactmenu a{
}
```

I removed that and works fine.

Comment: I don't see how that would conflict with anything, but at least you got it working.